# How do I reduce the memory usage in this c# File Transfer?

Tags: c#, file, memory, allocation, transfer

I have a simple file transfer app written in c# using TCP to send the data.

This is how I send files:

```
Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fName); //file name
        byte[] fileData =  new byte[1000*1024];
        byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileName.Length); //length of file name
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(textBox1.Text, FileMode.Open);            
        try
        {
            clientData = new byte[4 + fileName.Length];
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryException exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Out of memory");
            return;
        }

        fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
        fileName.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
        clientSock.Connect("172.16.12.91", 9050);
        clientSock.Send(clientData, 0, clientData.Length, SocketFlags.None);                       
        progressBar1.Maximum = (int)fs.Length;
        while (true)
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (index < fs.Length)
            {
                int bytesRead = fs.Read(fileData, index, fileData.Length - index);
                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                index += bytesRead;
            }
            if (index != 0)
            {
                clientSock.Send(fileData, index, SocketFlags.None);
                if ((progressBar1.Value + (1024 * 1000)) > fs.Length)
                {
                    progressBar1.Value += ((int)fs.Length - progressBar1.Value);
                }
                else
                    progressBar1.Value += (1024 * 1000);
            }

            if (index != fileData.Length)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                clientSock.Close();
                fs.Close();

                break;

            } 
        }            

    }
```

In taskmanager,the Release version of this app's memory usage goes 13 MB when I use the OpenFileDialog, then goes up to 16 MB when it sends data then stays there. Is there anything I can do to reduce the memory usage? Or is there a good tool that I can use to monitor the total allocation memory in the app?

And while we're there, is 16 MB really that high?

Comment: 16MB isn't that high. And why do you want to reduce the memory footprint? Is there any need? Seems to be a premature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

16MB doesn't sound that much of memory usage.
You could use the inbuilt visual studio profiler to see what's costing the most performance. See link below for more information about the profiler:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2009/06/10/write-faster-code-with-vs-2010-profiler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I minimize any app, the memory usage goes down quite significantly. I eventually looked for a way to replicate this effect programmatically and this is what I found:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool SetProcessWorkingSetSize(IntPtr proc, int min, int max);
        public void ReleaseMemory()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
            {
                SetProcessWorkingSetSize(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, -1, -1);
            }
        }
```

I don't know the cons in using this but so far, it managed to save at least 13MB of memory.

Comment: Can I ask why? I'm new to this

Comment: You never want to force a system to GC because you are now introducing unnecessary collection of objects.  The Garbage Collector should be allowed to GC things when it wants to do that.  By forcing it, you are affecting the performance of not just your app, but the system under which it runs.  Let the runtime do its thing and let it do it when it thinks it is appropriate to do so.

Comment: EDIT: I discourage the use of this method (unless you need exactly what it does) since it doesn't "reduce" memory at all.